iOS Broadcast extension and file recording
I am facing some issues with broadcast extension and saving video samples, mic and app audio to a mp4 file. My issues are two.
The first one is that sometimes, I do not know why, while the pop up for the screen recording starts, and my broadcast extention is selected, I press the start recording, the countdown starts from 3 and when it reaches zero, it goes again to start recording.  I remove the app from the iphone and restart the phone. I install again the app and I repeat this process until it starts recording. At some point it will start recording. I can not find why this is happening and why there is no error so I can debug what is happening. The extension and the app has the same AppGroup that starts with the ‘group.’ prefix, the Entitlements are the same.
The second issue has to do with the recording itself. For the process of writing to the file, I have used the BroadcastWritter from the github repo of romiroma. The issue here is that when swapping between apps, some audio samples seems to get dropped. As a result the audio gets out of sync.
I have tried to change the app group to contain the team Id but with no luck. As for the second part of my question I can not think of why this is happening.
Thanks for the help

I have tried more things but with no luck.  I have tried to get the time of the system when when it starts recording using CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CACurrentMediaTime(), preferredTimescale: 1000) and then on the processSampleBuffer get the current time and use CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming in order to set a new timing for the audio, with no luck.
